# Why are some of my inline tooltips out of alignment?

Tags: html, css, alignment, tooltip

I have added tooltips to some inline links on my portfolio website, but only the first one lines up properly from to the bottom of its container using `bottom: 100%`.

The others are a few pixels higher, and I've tried adjusting so many different things to see what's affecting the other two, but can't figure it out. When I apply a background color to the `.tooltip-container` spans, they are clearly the same height.

How do I correctly position these tooltips?

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 70px);
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.4);
  z-index: 30;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.tooltip:before, .tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip, a:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>&copy; 2021 Caroline R. Jones &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            LinkedIn
            <span class="tooltip">
              Visit my full profile
            </span>
          </span>
        </a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            HackerRank
            <span class="tooltip">
              View my badges and certificates
            </span>
          </span>
        </a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            GitHub
            <span class="tooltip">
              Check out my repos and contributions
            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </p>
</div>
```

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/carolista/pen/MWEwGQy) with just the relevant code isolated. It is behaving the same here as it does on the actual website.

Comment: @Joundill why did you feel the need to edit my question? There's nothing wrong with me thanking people in advance for taking the time to help me. That's just common courtesy.

Comment: Have a read of this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1):

It's because the ones that are off by a few pixels have two rows of text. Hence, why the spacing is off. What I would do is set `white-space: nowrap;` on your `tooltip` so that they are all on one line. I also changed your fixed width of `120px` to `width: fit-content;`

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 70px);
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.4);
  z-index: 30;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip:before, .tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip, a:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>&copy; 2021 Caroline R. Jones &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            LinkedIn
            <span class="tooltip">
              Visit my full profile
            </span>
          </span>
        </a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            HackerRank
            <span class="tooltip">
              View my badges and certificates
            </span>
          </span>
        </a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            GitHub
            <span class="tooltip">
              Check out my repos and contributions
            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `white-space: no-wrap` - that is a possible solution, but I've seen plenty of instances where people have tooltips of varying height and don't have the alignment issue and I'd like to have that flexibility and limit the width. 

I did actually experiment with `width: fit-content` but then I couldn't figure out how to dynamically calculate the offset so that the arrow would always center on the link horizontally. I see in your snippet that it's still an issue. Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new to css, so apologies if this isn't correct, but it looks to be based on the font-size. I changed the font-size to about 8px, and everything worked as intended. So switching that back, in your final class, I have changed the translateY(-50%) from a percentage to a set number (in this case -1.5vh). This seems to have fixed the issue.

```
 .tooltip-container:hover .tooltip, a:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-1.5vh);
  }
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  
  .tooltip-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: calc(50% - 70px);
    background: #222;
    color: white;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.4);
    z-index: 30;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  
  .tooltip:before, .tooltip:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #222;
  }
  
  .tooltip-container:hover .tooltip, a:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-1.5vh);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="./interface.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <p>&copy; 2021 Caroline R. Jones &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            LinkedIn
            <span class="tooltip">
              Visit my full profile
            </span>
          </span>
        </a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            HackerRank
            <span class="tooltip">
              View my badges and certificates
            </span>
          </span>
        </a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <span class="tooltip-container">
            GitHub
            <span class="tooltip">
              Check out my repos and contributions
            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing the `translateY` on the transition definitely does the trick. Seems like I can make the font size whatever I want as long as that is based on something other than its own height. I think I assumed that the 50% was tied to the container and not the height of the tooltip, which does vary. It also explains why on another part of my website, where the tooltips were all a single line, it was aligned consistently. In this instance I was too focused on the `bottom: 100%` and didn't think about the `transform`!

Comment: Glad it helped!